# Accessing SurfaceView of an Activity in IntentService

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, intentservice

Key Point: My application should be capable of running in background.

A rough structure of my application calls is:

`HomeActivity(AppCompatActivity) -> MainActivity(AppCompatActivity) -> CameraRecorderService(IntentService) AND SensorService(Service)`

Brief Explanation: On a button press in `HomeActivity`, `MainActivity` is triggered using Intent. As soon as `MainActivity` is called, in its `onCreate()` method, I call the two services i.e. `CameraRecorderService` and `SensorService`.

The `CameraRecorderService` records the video in an infinite loop unless it receives an event from `SensorService`.

The current application is working completely fine unless the app goes in background, i.e. I press the home button. It gives `D/Camera﹕ app passed NULL surface` , `E/MediaRecorderJNI﹕ Application lost the surface`.

The relevant code for `MainActivity` and `CameraRecorderService` are:

"MainActivity.java"

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

public static SurfaceView mSurfaceView; //declared static so that it can be accessed by Services
public static SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView1);
    mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
    mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SensorService.class);
    intent2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startService(intent2);

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CameraRecorderService.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startService(intent);

    ImageButton btnStop = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.stop);
    btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, CameraRecorderService.class));
            stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SensorService.class));
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

}
```

"CameraRecorderService.java"

```
public class CameraRecorderService extends IntentService {

public CameraRecorderService(){
    super("CameraRecorderService");
}

private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
private static Camera mServiceCamera;
private boolean mRecordingStatus;
private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;
static boolean accidentStatus = false;
boolean manualStopStatus = false;
int accidentOnVideoIndex = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mSurfaceView = MainActivity.mSurfaceView; //Getting the surface from Activity
    mSurfaceHolder = MainActivity.mSurfaceHolder;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    manualStopStatus = true;
    if(mRecordingStatus){
        stopRecording();
    }
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    while(!accidentStatus){
        int i =1;
        while(i < 3) {
            if (!accidentStatus && !manualStopStatus) {
                accidentOnVideoIndex = i;
                startRecording("someName" + i);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    if(mRecordingStatus)
                        stopRecording();

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                i++;
            }else{
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(!manualStopStatus) {

        startRecording("someName3");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            stopRecording();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public boolean startRecording(String fileName){
    try {
        mRecordingStatus = true;
        mServiceCamera = Camera.open();
        Camera.Parameters p = mServiceCamera.getParameters();

        final List<Camera.Size> listSize = p.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        Camera.Size mPreviewSize = listSize.get(2);
        Log.v(TAG, "use: width = " + mPreviewSize.width
                + " height = " + mPreviewSize.height);
        p.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
        p.setPreviewFormat(PixelFormat.YCbCr_420_SP);
        mServiceCamera.setParameters(p);
        mServiceCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        try {
            mServiceCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder);
            mServiceCamera.startPreview();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mServiceCamera.unlock();

        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mServiceCamera);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        mMediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P));
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/somePath/" + fileName + ".mp4");

        mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder.getSurface());

        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
        mMediaRecorder.start();

        return true;
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

public void stopRecording() {       
    mRecordingStatus = false;
    try {
        mServiceCamera.reconnect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mMediaRecorder.stop();
    mMediaRecorder.reset();

    mServiceCamera.stopPreview();
    mMediaRecorder.release();

    mServiceCamera.release();
    mServiceCamera = null;
}

public static class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("Accident!!");
        accidentStatus = true;
    }
}
```

I think the problem is that the `SurfaceView` is destroyed when Activity goes in `onPause()` state and as I have used a `static SurfaceView` it is nullified. And so the `CameraRecorderService(IntentService)` does not get the value from Activity because it runs on a separate thread.

But how do I solve this problem? As I said, the application works fine in foreground but the main purpose of my application is to run in background. Any suggestions are welcome!